# JWT.h file not found when building iOS App

Tags: ios

I'm new in iOs development and I try to build one app that one of our senior developers give to me.
After I install pods and run pod install and even try pod build there is still error:

> JWT.h file not found.

In project settings I add `$(PODS_ROOT)/JWT` but noting changed.
Please give me some advice what to do.

Comment: There are a few libraries called JWT, do you have any more info? There's even a `Java Web Toolkit`. But I assume you're in need of the following: https://github.com/yourkarma/JWT -- install that using the pod: `pod 'JWT'`.

Comment: The pod install command in project folder is showing this:

`pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Base64 (1.1.2)
Using Bolts (1.8.4)
Using JWT (2.2.0)
Using Parse (1.14.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 2 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.`

Comment: Alright, so `JWT` is now installed. Try changing `#import "JWT.h"` to `#import <JWT/JWT.h>` now. That should most likely include the right JWT header.

Comment: I've tried this, but there is no difference

Comment: Could you try and post a picture of your project settings, more specifically your `Linked Frameworks and Libraries` section?

Comment: Here image of Linked Frameworks and Libraries - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tWiH.png

Comment: Actually, that looks OK. Pods is linked, so no problem with that. Do you see `JWT` in the pods directory?

Comment: Yes, in Pods directory there is JWT and the JWT.h file is in `Pods/JWT/Classes/JWT.h`

Comment: Phew, now I'm clueless. Usually `#import <JWT/JWT.h>` should work in your case.